# How to add user answers to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a project due in my online programming course and it tells me to make a program that calculates what level a student gets based on a submitted percentage mark along with certain statistics for that student.

And to do this I will have to make a prompt that repeats ten times and I will have to store this information to an array. All I have so far is a for loop as I cannot figure out how to store user information into an array.

```
for (var counter = 1; counter < 3; counter++) {
   var marks = prompt("What is your mark?");
   console.log("test");
}
```

Comment: Tell your teacher that 10 prompts is the most unintuitive way to teach user input with javascript.

Comment: PS next time try a google search "javascript add to array"

Comment: You already solve the hard part: You know that the thing you need is called an "array". Now you can look up how to create an array and what operations can be performed on an array. If have done that and are still stuck, let us know. (Also, your title is vague: It is not clear whether the problem is that you do not know how to get answers from the user, or that you don't know how to put those answers in an array once you got them. The fact that the answers came from the user isn't relevant. You just want to save things in an array.)

Comment: Have you looked at the [MDN docs on Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) *at all*?

Comment: I do know what an array is. Sorry if it is a little vague. I just cannot add user info, from the prompt, into an array. I can create them all day otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to store their responses into an array. You're currently storing it into the variable `marks` but you're not doing anything with it. Try just pushing the response straight into an array, then doing what you want with it.

```
var userMarks = [];
for (var counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
    userMarks.push(prompt("What is your mark?"));
}
console.log(userMarks);
// Do averages or whatever
```

Comment: I am using jsfiddle. And in the console at the bottom of the screen it only the last value entered appears in the array.

Comment: Can you link your jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to initialize an array outside of your loop then perform an [array push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) inside of it with the value retrieved from the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array on javascript like this

```
var markArray = [];
```

Then, you just need to add marks you collect from `prompt`. For this, you can use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) Array method

```
markArray.push(mark);
```

Since you're learning, I'll let you connect this with your code instead of giving you the final code, it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score -1):

You need to store the prompt value into an array.
have a look to javascript push spec:

That should work:

```
var marks = [];
for (var counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++) {
   marks.push(prompt("What is your mark?"));
}
console.log(marks);
```

Comment: that'll only produce 9 marks, and please, never reference w3schools.com!